# Unable to obtain sum in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, defaultdict

I am trying to do sum up all the values in my dictionary for each key. So far, I am using a defaultdict and this is my dictionary:
`scores = {10: [[1000], [1000]], 25: [[500],[500],[500]], 40: [[600]], 60: [[700]]}`

I want it so that `10: 2000` `20: 1500`

So this is my code:
`finalScores = {k:sum(v) for k,v in scores.items()}`

But instead, I am getting this error: `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'`

I know it is because I have a list of a list, but like how do I convert it or like do sum

I am been having a huge headache over this

Comment: Why do you even have those one-element sublists? Why are your values not plain lists of ints? The best approach is probably to change your earlier code to not produce those sublists.

Answer (score 2):

Use `itertools.chain` to flatten each list.

```
from itertools import chain
{k: sum(chain.from_iterable(v)) for k, v in scores.items()}
```

`chain.from_iterable` is a class method that, given something like `[[a,b,c], [d,e,f]]`, produces an iterator that yields values from each sublist in turn.

Answer (score 0):

In case you cannot change the input, you can use a recursive function that will sum all the values inside a list of lists (or a deeper level).

```
def sum_list(l):
    if isinstance(l, int):
        return l
    else:
        return sum(map(lambda x: sum_list(x), l))


scores = {10: [[1000], [1000]], 25: [[500], [500], [500]], 40: [[600]], 60: [[700]]}
result = {k: sum_list(v) for k,v in scores.items()}

print(result)
```

> > {10: 2000, 25: 1500, 40: 600, 60: 700}

Answer (score 0):

Flatten the list of lists with `sum(v,[])` before summing it:

```
scores = {10: [[1000], [1000]], 25: [[500],[500],[500]], 40: [[600]], 60: [[700]]}
finalScores = {k:sum(sum(v,[])) for k,v in scores.items()}
print(finalScores)
```

Output:

```
{10: 2000, 25: 1500, 40: 600, 60: 700}
```

Comment: `sum` is a terrible, quadratic-time way to flatten nested lists.

Comment: Is it such a terrible choice here considering the lengths of the lists in OP's data?

Comment: Yes, because there's no reason to expect the values to always be that small.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply a single function to a list of objects that will all respond to that function, you want a call to `map()`:

```py
map(sum, [[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]) # => [5, 9] ... sort of*
```

Python programmers normally prefer a list comprehension for this kind of thing:

```py
[sum(list) for list in list_of_lists]
```

Which is very similar to the dict comprehension you are already doing, and could either be combined like so:

```py
{k: sum(l) for (k, ll) in scores.items() for l in ll}
```

or separated out into some logic elsewhere as well.

I am not precisely sure what the point of the innermost level of list nesting is, as it seems like all of your innermost lists are simply singletons. I suppose this could just be because of your example, but it might also be worthwhile to see if you can refactor to only need one level of nesting.

As a final note, in general when dealing with lists of lists, it might be helpful to look to the venerable [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module in the stdlib, or another more comprehensive offshoot like [more-itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), which just so happens to provide a [`flatten()`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.flatten) function! (Although as another answerer points out, you can use `chain.from_iterable` to achieve the same thing out of the box from `itertools`)

*the caveat with `map()` is that it actually returns a `map` object, which will iterate over the mapped values.

Answer (score 0):

A `numpy` solution:

```
import numpy as np
{k: np.sum(l) for k,l in scores.items()}
```